# django: assertRedirect clears session data django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Django and I'm writing a simple accounting app. Now I've started to write some test cases for this app.

There is a `profile` form in my app that allows user to edit his or her profile. If the data has been successfully changed, I call `HttpResponseRedirect` to `index` page

I use an `assertRedirect` method to ensure that when the form data is correct the page is redirected to the `index` page

But when I call this method in my `TestCase` class, I see that it clears session data and the user is no more logged in

Here is some parts of my code:

```
class TestEditProfile(TestCase):

    def test_change_password(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('account:profile'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, 'First name')
        data = self.get_user_data()
        response = self.client.post(reverse('account:profile'), data=data)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('account:index'))
```

When I debug my program, I see that after calling `self.assertRedirects` the User session data will be cleared and the user is no more logged in so if I want to `post` some request to `profile` page it ignores it because the `profile` view is `login_required`

Is there a problem in my code or something else?

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE:** I took a deeper look in code using `pydev debugger` and realized that this method clears user session data:

```
if fetch_redirect_response:
    redirect_response = response.client.get(path, QueryDict(query),
                                                secure=(scheme == 'https'))
```

**The source code is line 320 of file: testcase.py**

before running this line `self.client.session._session` had size 3 and had keys:`'_auth_user_backend' (4413833840)`, `'_auth_user_hash' (4411636976)` and `'_auth_user_id' (4408855216)` But after running this line `self.client.session._session` is completely cleared!

Comment: Sorry, but did you call the method manually or by `python manage.py test`?

Comment: How are you seeing this? Do you have more code in that same method, or is a separate test method?

Comment: I use `python manage.py test`.There are some few more things in the code, but there are not important because when I debug the code using pycharm debugger, I realize that after calling the mentioned method, user session data will be cleared! @daniel-roseman @irvind